# scrapy trouble with xpath on google.com

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

There is one bug in scrapy or my mistake .

```
class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    start_urls =["http://www.google.ru/search?q=gabber"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath("//div[@id='ires']/ol/li/h3[@class='r']")
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['url'] = site.xpath("//li[@class='g']/h3/a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

The problem is  item search element on whole page , not in 'sites'.
On other sites(like dmoz) works correctly(search only in 'sites' element). 
I suppose this is scrapy bug ?

Comment: `//` starts absolute path and it means to search on whole page. Use dot at the beginning `.//` to make relative path. Or use something shorter without dot and `//` like `a/@href`.

Comment: see: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths

Comment: Thank you,Furas!!!
I spent whole night searching this bug . 
And solution is simple - a/@href .
Thanks a lot :) 
Have a nice Happy  New Year time :)